# How much willpower do gravely wounded soliders lose?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

How much willpower do gravely wounded soldiers lose? The text says they suffer a permanent reduction?

Comment: btw. "permanent" means "not restored with medkit" or "not restored ever".

Comment: @vartec, ever. They stay at their reduced will until the end, and have to be actually dismissed from service, as our Fremen friend below describes :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my current Classic Iron Man game using both Iron Will and New Guy from the Training school I have:

- A Heavy Squaddie that was gravely hurt once at 36 will
- A Heavy Captain that was gravely hurt 2 or 3 times at 17 will!
- A newly recruited Heavy Squaddie (never hurt) is 45 will.

I'm sure I had the Captain before I bought Iron Will, but at what point I don't know. I can't go back and calculate exact values because of the whole Iron Man thing.

<strike>I'd guess its around -10 to -12 Will for a grave injury. It's probably a range.</strike>

Needless to say that Captain with 17 Will has seen her last mission. She panics when a window breaks.

---

**Update:**

I’ve been tracking these stats the last couple of nights: I had a my supper star support Colonel get gravely hurt twice. His will went from 91 to 81 and then to 67.

**So new confirmed range is: -10 to -14.**

Comment: Interesting how it mirror's PTSD

Comment: It isn't reduced though, with "normal" wounded (i.e. not gravely)?

Comment: I don't think it happens on every 'gravely wounded' attempts either.  In my latest classic iron man attempt last night, I had a squaddie that was gravely wounded (out for 18 days) but ended up with a will of 47 (well within normal squaddie will range, actually considered upper bound for a squaddie before the iron will upgrade).

Comment: @StampedeXV - True, “normal” wounds don’t change Will. As far as I can tell the real measure is whether they are critically wounded (unconscious and bleeding out) on the battlefield. Obviously critically wounded results in a “grave” wound… So I’m not exactly sure which is the trigger.

Comment: Lol. @spartacus and I commented within 1 minute of eachother. Put the two comments together and I think we have the answer...

Comment: @Stilgar I think that's it.  It requires a knockout in combat to lose will

Comment: i am playing classic- no ironman- so i have been saving. i saved before the mission and after the mission. Had a gravely wounded soldier so i check before and after and he only drop 2 points.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a major critically wounded and after the mission his Will sat at 70. Before the mission it was 100 and i know this because i just had him qualify for Psi-abilities from the psi-labs prior to the mission.

I suppose the drop in will isn't an issue in this circumstance since he's already psi-qualified and 70 is sufficient to not have issues in a mission. But 30 is a damn lot.

Even though this question is a year old i thought i'd reply anyway since it ranks high in the google search and the game has been on steam sale recently and probably seeing a lot more activity.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between "gravely" and "critically" wounded.
Gravely wounded soldiers lose some willpower for the remainder of the mission; but not permanently. Critically wounded lose their willpower permanently.

Citation:

> **Injured:**
>  
>   If a soldier is injured during combat, for the remainder of
>   the mission they are subject to a Will penalty, visible as "Battle
>   Fatigue" when viewing the soldier info interface. If injured by less
>   than 50% of their total health, the penalty is -5 Will. If injured by
>   more than 50% of their total health, the penalty is -10 Will.
>
> **Critically Wounded**
>  
>   When a soldier loses all of their HP during a
>   mission, they either die or become critically wounded. Soldiers of a
>   higher rank are more likely to be critically wounded instead of dying.
>   Critically wounded soldiers must be stabilized or revived with a
>   Medikit or they will bleed out and die in three turns (including the
>   turn they were injured), if the mission is not completed by then.
>   Critically wounded soldiers, even if saved, incur a permanent -10 (-15
>   on Classic or Impossible) reduction to Will. In XCOM: Enemy Within,
>   this penalty can be avoided with the Secondary Heart Gene Mod.
>
> Critically wounded soldiers are not targeted by enemies, but can be
>   killed before bleeding out in the event of an explosion. Take care
>   while fighting enemies that are equipped with explosives or explode
>   upon death (such as Cyberdiscs), as well as near combustible objects
>   in the environment (such as vehicles).
>
> **Gravely Wounded**
>   When a soldier is heavily (but not critically)
>   wounded, they are considered to be gravely wounded. Other than an
>   increased recuperation time in the Infirmary, this status is the same
>   as wounded. It does not require stabilization or entail critically
>   wounded's Will reduction penalty.

Source: http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Soldier_(XCOM:_Enemy_Unknown)#Mortality