# Cap on permanent Will penalties?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

A critically wounded soldier who recovers gets a permanent Will penalty due to the psychological trauma. Does this stack for each time the soldier has to recover? If so, what's the limit on how low a soldier's Will can go? Does the penalty eventually stop stacking? Do low-Will soldiers always die instead of getting critically wounded? Or can I eventually deploy negative-Will panicky messes?

Comment: Closely related: [How much willpower do gravely wounded soliders lose?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/90111/88)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The answer to that other question says nothing about whether the penalty stops stacking at some point, or what happens when a soldier's base Will hits zero.

Comment: [Someone's managed to get negative Will in Long War.](http://imgur.com/Q9MfZcF) Dunno about vanilla.

Comment: I wonder if that sign is treated correctly or whether a -100  soldier will never panic...

Answer (score 3):

There are no caps on how low Will can fall, except that it never goes negative.

It *might* be possible for it to fall to 0, but that would take some doing.  By the time your soldier's will gets low enough that you could hit 0, the soldier will be panicing at the drop of a hat.  Any time a window breaks, they would panic.

By that point, your soldier will be effectively unusable in missions.